# Add a control to the selected PivotItem

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a Windows Phone 8.1 App (WinRT).

I have a Pivot `MainPagePivot` and added `pivotItems` to it but I am not adding any content to any `pivotitem`. I am getting the selected index of this Pivot using code:

```
int index = MainPagePivot.SelectedIndex;
```

Now whenever user swipes to the `pivotitem`, a TextBlock must be created inside the selected `pivotitem`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
(MainPagePivot.SelectedItem as PivotItem).Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "Hello WP!" };
```